# проблема с django. Выводит ошибку:ImportError: cannot import name 'hello' from 'studyproject.views'

Tags: django

Начал изучать Джанго. Делал свой первый проэкт и, неуспев толком что-либо сделать, уже ошибка.
        код urls.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),# BUG:
    path('blog/', hello)
```

код views.py:

```
def hello(request):
    pass
```

командная строка выдаёт вот это:[image: ошибка:ImportError: cannot import name 'hello' from 'studyproject.views']

Comment: А вы создавали приложение? Где лежит файл views.py?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно создать приложение, для этого в терминале нужно набрать команду (находясь в директории с manage.py):

```
python manage.py startapp blog
```

При этом в папке проекта появится папка blog с файлами, в том числе views.py

Вот в этом файле и должна лежать ваша тестовая функция:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Привет, я работаю')
```

Дальше нужно создать в папке blog файл urls.py вот с таким содержимым:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import hello

urlpatterns = [
    path('', hello)
]
```

Затем нужно включить содержимое файла urls.py в основной файл urls.py (который в той же папке, что и settings.py), для этого используется функция include:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

P.S. Судя по всему вы не используете виртуальное окружение. Для учебных целей может это еще и норм, но в целом лучше использовать, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Ты импортируешь `views` в проект `project`, а нужно в приложение `python manage.py startapp blog` создать там `urls.py`, прописать

```
from blog import views 
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [ url(r'', views.index, name='index')]
```

А во views.py

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 def index(request):
     return HttpResponse('Hello')
```

Comment: Или я что-то делаю не так, или даже с вашими модификациями оно не работает.

Comment: это наверное для для старых версий подойдет, сейчас вроде вместо функции url нужно использовать path при роутинге